# Scala unexpectedly not being able to ascertain type for expanded function

Tags: scala

Why, in Scala, given:

```
a = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
def f(x : String) = { x }
```

does

```
a.map(_.toString)
```

work, but

```
a.map(f(_.toString))
```

give the error

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toString)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well... `f()` takes a String as a parameter. The construct `_.toString` has type `A <: Any => String`. The function `f()` expects a type of `String`, so the example above does not type check. It seems that Scala is friendly in this case and gives the user another chance. The error message means: "By my type inference algorithms this does not compile. Put the types in and it might, if it's something I can't infer."

You would have to write the anonymous function longhand in this case, i.e. `a.map(n => f(n.toString))`. This is not a limitation of type inference, but of the wildcard symbol. Basically, when you write `a.map(f(_.toString))`, the `_.toString` gets expanded into an anonymous function inside the closest brackets it can find, otherwise this would lead to enormous ambiguity. Imagine something like `f(g(_.toString))`. Does this mean `f(g(x => x.toString))` or `f(x => g(x.toString))`? Worse ambiguities would arise for multiple nested function calls. The Scala type checker therefore takes the most logical solution, as described above.

Nitpick: the first line of your code should be `val a = List(1,2,3,4)` :).