# Why do I get a "missing parameter for expanded function" in one case and not the other?

Tags: scala

Case this works:

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach (println(_))
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach (throw new Exception(_.toString))
```

Compilation ends with this error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$4) => x$4.toString)
```

Now if I write it this way it compiles again:

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach (s => throw new Exception(s.toString))
```

I am sure there is a reasonable explanation ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This has already been addressed in [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545168/scala-unexpectedly-not-being-able-to-ascertain-type-for-expanded-function). Underscores extend outwards to the closest closing `Expr` : top-level expressions or expressions in parentheses.

`(_.toString)` is an expression in parentheses. The argument you are passing to `Exception` in the error case is therefore, after expansion, the full anonymous function `(x$1) => x$1.toString` of type `A <: Any => String`, while `Exception` expects a `String`.

In the `println` case, `_` by itself isn't of syntactic category `Expr`, but `(println (_))` is, so you get the expected `(x$0) => println(x$0)`.

Comment: Thanks. Now a related question is whether in such cases, the compiler could still support the `_` as a shortcut. Any cases where this wouldn't work "as expected"?

Answer (score 9):

The difference is whether `_` stands for the whole parameter, or is part of an expression. Depending on which, it falls into one of the two following categories:

### Partially Applied Function

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach (println(_))
```

translates into

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach ((x$1) => println(x$1))
```

### Anonymous Function Parameter

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach (throw new Exception(_.toString))
```

translates into

```
Seq(fromDir, toDir) find (!_.isDirectory) foreach (throw new Exception((x$1) => x$1.toString))
```