# missing parameter type for expanded function for my function; not for another with same signature

Tags: scala, lambda, pattern-matching, function-literal

**Short form**:  I have a method with the same signature as `Future.recover`.  Passing a partial function to `Future`'s version works.  Passing the same PF to my version results in a `missing parameter type for expanded function. The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)` error.  What's the difference?

**Longer form**: 
I'm trying to implement the `TracingFuture` class discussed [here](https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/tracing-back-scala-future-chains/) in an attempt to trace errors across future boundaries.  The basic technique is to wrap the Future in another class, `TracingFuture`, while adding a pseudo-stacktrace.

The code given in the blog post is missing the `recover` method from `Future`, so I've added it with the same signature:

```
class TracingFuture[+T](underlying: Future[T], val trace: Vector[FutureTraceElement]) extends Future[T] {

  def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]
                     )(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, enclosing: sourcecode.Enclosing, file: sourcecode.File,
                       line: sourcecode.Line): TracingFuture[U] = {
    val recovered = underlying.recover(pf)
    new TracingFuture[U](recovered, trace :+ FutureTraceElement(enclosing.value, "recover", file.value, line.value))

  }

}
```

For comparison, here's the equivalent chunk of code out of `Future`. Note that aside from the extra implicit parameters the signatures are the same.

```
trait Future[+T] extends Awaitable[T] {

  def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U] =
    transform { _ recover pf }
}
```

Finally, my code that produces the compile error:

```
val x: TracingFuture[Vector[Maintainer]] = ... // code producing a TracingFuture
val fMaintainers = x.recover {
  case err: Throwable ⇒
    logger.error("Failed to get list of user maintainers.", err)
    Vector.empty[Maintainer]
}
```

And the error message:

```
[error] /Users/bwbecker/oat/src/oat3/modules/wapp/app/oat/wapp/dao/CronJobDAO.scala:273: missing parameter type for expanded function
[error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: ?
[error]     val fMaintainers = x.recover {
[error]                                  ^
```

Once again, this code works with the `Future.recover` but I get a compile error with `TracingFuture.recover`.  I don't understand why.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869251/the-argument-types-of-an-anonymous-function-must-be-fully-known-sls-8-5) explains that the compiler knows the argument to the partial function must be a supertype of T but can't guarantee that.  But why doesn't it run into that issue with `Future.recover`?

And, of course, I'd like to know if there's anything I do about it other than rewriting the anonymous partial function to make the types explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `TracingFuture` has two overloaded `recover` methods: the one you added and the one you inherited from `Future`. When you only have one, it provides the expected type which is crucial for type inference, but with overloaded methods it doesn't work, as you see from `Expected type was: ?`.

You may think the compiler should notice types of function parameters are the same and so can still provide the expected type. And you would be right, but [it was only fixed in Scala 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types).

Of course, then you'll run into trouble that the compiler has no way to tell which overload you want when only the implicit arguments are different.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey, for the quick and informative reply.  I gave my recover method a different name and, as expected according to what you say here, the compile error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
val fMaintainers = x.recover {
  case err: Throwable ⇒
    logger.error("Failed to get list of user maintainers.", err)
    Vector.empty[Maintainer]
}
```

with

```
val fMaintainers = x.recover(PartialFunction[Throwable, Vector[Maintainer]] { 
  case err: Throwable ⇒
    logger.error("Failed to get list of user maintainers.", err)
    Vector.empty[Maintainer]
})
```

[Why do I get a "missing parameter for expanded function" in one case and not the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701761/why-do-i-get-a-missing-parameter-for-expanded-function-in-one-case-and-not-the)

Comment: Answers there don't seem to be relevant to this question, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Dmytro, thanks for the quick and informative reply.  I need to decide whether to just rename my version of the recover function or annotate the the types as you suggest.  Still pondering that one...