# Why can I not flatMap a List[Option] using underscore?

Tags: scala

Why can I write

```
val flat: List[Int] = List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatMap(i => i)
```

But not

```
val flat: List[Int] = List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatMap(_)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underscore is a placeholder for a variable. It's not, in and of itself, a function. `flatMap` requires a function.

Also, in this case, there is a `flatten` method which is defined on `List` for which `Option` has within the `Predef` an implicit conversion such that what you've written can be condensed into just that call, `List(Some(1)).flatten`

Comment: Is there a better way to flatmap the identity other than x => x?

Comment: @DanielSkogquistÅborg updated. It's called `flatten` and only works on identical `M[_]` or for `Iterables` with `Option`.

Comment: You can also use `identity` which is defined as `def identity[A](x: A): A         = x` in `Predef.scala` where a convenience like `flatten` isn't at hand.

Answer (score 2):

By rules for underscore `List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatMap(_)` is short for `x => List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatMap(x)`, not `List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatMap(x => x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the underscore can refer to an identity mapping, e.g. `x => x`, **but** `flatMap` requires a mapping to `TraversableOnce[U]` such as a list of items.

For example, `List(1, 2).flatMap(Seq(_))` works. `List(1, 2).map(_ + 2)` also works. The first one is just identity mapping and the second one will return `List(3, 4)`.

However, if you have complex transformation in the `flatMap` of `map` (more than one operator), you will have to write the lambda function properly, otherwise the compiler cannot correctly infer the type. See [Scala unexpectedly not being able to ascertain type for expanded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545168/scala-unexpectedly-not-being-able-to-ascertain-type-for-expanded-function).