# spark use underscore as parameter to RDD.flatmap or map

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd, flatmap

Here is my `data:RDD[Array[String]]` in spark. And I want to count the sum of all the elements length in data.

For example, `data:(Array(1,2),Array(1,2,3))`. I want to get the sum: 2+3=5;
At first, I use ：`data.flatMap(_).count()`,

Error :

> error: missing parameter type for expanded function `((x$1) =>
>   data.flatMap(x$1))`

But when I replace `_` with `x=>x` and write: `data.flatMap(x=>x).count()`, it works. So I am confused by the `_` . I think in scala `_` can be referred as the actual parameter type, right?

Comment: No idea why this is duplicate, a short answer is `_` is not `x => x`, but `_ + 1` is `x => x + 1` and `_.toArray[Int]` is `x => x.toArray[Int]`. If you use the last one in your code, it will achieve the same result.  A rule of thumb is to use `_` only and only if you have **one** operator to be applied, not two and not zero.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598649/why-can-i-not-flatmap-a-listoption-using-underscore).

Essentially, _ itself does not define a function. It can be used as a placeholder for a variable name when used in the anonymous function syntax, but when used by itself it means nothing.